# Passport UUID, Cliend UUID and User UUID

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, uuid, laravel-passport

I just created a new laravel project where I'll use passport for auth.
My users have UUID and installed passport with the UUID option.
things I've noticed...
passport's id is a primary string of 100 characters

`($table->string('id',100)->primary())`

user ID is a unsignedBigIncrement , nullable in some cases and index

`$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index()`

Cliend ID, with the --uuid option is a uuid

`$table->uuid('cliend_id')`

now my question is, first, has anyone changed the passport tables to
`uuid('id')->primary()` instead of `string('id',100)->primary()`, and if so, does it affect at all.

Second, I tend to use foreign UUID in most of my tables, so is it worth writing an extra layer of...

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
->references('id)
->on('users')
->onDelete('cascade')
```

and...

```
$table->foreign('client_id')
->references('id)
->on('oauth_clients')
->onDelete('cascade')
```

just to keep things better organized, or should I just run with it???